# android: save capture photo 0kb in the folder

Tags: java, android, android-camera, bitmapimage

after taking a photo, my photo display in activity, but when i check into folder, the size from my photo is 0kb, i have no idea why this happen, and when i take a photo again, the new photo not save in the folder that i wanted, this is my code :

```
 {


                    File sdCard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File path = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/android/data/spaj_foto");
            path.mkdir();
            File file= new File (path,"spaj_foto.png");          
             outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
              Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
              cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri  );
              startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,TAKE_PHOTO_CODE ); 

                }

@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                 if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data"); 
                image_spaj.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Picture was not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
               } 
            }


        }
```

**EDIT**

this is my logcat :

```
    09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {org.example.touch/org.example.touch.FormSpaj}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3222)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at org.example.touch.FormSpaj.onActivityResult(FormSpaj.java:990)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
09-26 17:57:38.072: E/AndroidRuntime(12498):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4):

You have created a new file. (blank)

And then started a camera intent.

But what you have not done, is told the camera intent where to save the image.

Thus, leaving you with a blank file.

```
  File file= new File (path,"spaj_foto.png");


  outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
  Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
  cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri  );
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,TAKE_PHOTO_CODE );
```

Note, you do Not need to create the file, android camera intent will do that for you.
What you do need to do is pass the extra, so the intent knows where to save.

(you do still need to create the directory)

Comment: i don't get it, can you more specific?

Comment: i got eror, please see above, i have add my logcat

Comment: @AoyamaNanami This is another error, unrelated to your first question. In your `onActivtyResult` method, you appear to have a `nullpointer`. Which I believe is due to `image_spaj` not being set. Intialise `image_spaj` first. `image_spaj = findViewById(...)`

Comment: @AoyamaNanami I assume you changed the dots to your actual image views ID?.. Plus I assume the image is now saving correctly, and is no longer 0KB.